# How to merge duplicate records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, large-data

I have post_view_counters table with 11 million row.

```
id    post_id    start_date    end_date    views
_________________________________________________
1       55          XXXX         YYYY        90
2       55          XXXX         YYYY        1
3       55          XXXX         YYYY        1
```

there are duplicate records for some reason (bug in backend) which already fixed.
I need merge all rows views with same **post_id**, **start_date** and **end_date**
result should be like this after update table

```
id    post_id    start_date    end_date    views
_________________________________________________
1       55          XXXX         YYYY        92
```

Comment: Is the table MyISAM or InnoDB ? Are there any indexes defined on the table ? Are you going to be doing this changes on production directly (like when table is actually in use by your apps) ? Since it is a big table, answers will vary depending on the severity of affecting production.

Comment: start_date end_date should be same for all rows

Comment: So you want to DELETE the Duplicates so there is only one row left on the table but with the correct view count

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, only one row with updated views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the safe approach:

First, create a new table -

```
CREATE TABLE post_view_counters_new LIKE post_view_counters;
```

Then insert the data into the new table-(syntax by @scaisEdge)

```
INSERT INTO post_view_counters_new 
SELECT MIN(id) id,  post_id ,   start_date ,   end_date ,   SUM( views) views
FROM post_view_counters
GROUP  BY  post_id ,   start_date ,   end_date;
```

After that, compare data between new table and old table. Once you're satisfied, rename old table to something like 'post_view_counters_old' and rename 'post_view_counters_new' to 'post_view_counters'. So, in case you're missing anything inside the new table, you still can refer back the old table.

Comment: Good answer +1; but again whether direct `delete` is better or `create .. insert` method; it all depends on how many duplicate rows are there actually, from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

for the same post_id ,   start_date ,   end_date  you could use aggregation function 
 as min(id)  , sum(view ) and group by

```
select min(id) id,  post_id ,   start_date ,   end_date ,   sum( views) views
from my_table  
group  by  post_id ,   start_date ,   end_date
```

Comment: I don't need select , I need that all rows will be updated in table

Comment: Guys, see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57784273/how-to-merge-duplicate-records-in-mysql#comment102002466_57784273) and answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select min(id),post_id,    start_date ,   end_date,sum(views)
from tablename
group by post_id, start_date, end_date
```

Comment: Guys, see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57784273/how-to-merge-duplicate-records-in-mysql#comment102002466_57784273) and answer below

Answer (score 0):

First you must update the rows with the min `id` for each `post_id, start_date, end_date`:

```
update tablename t inner join (
  select sum(views) views, min(id) id from tablename
  group by post_id, start_date, end_date
) tt
on tt.id = t.id 
set t.views = tt.views;
```

and then delete all the other ids keeping only the min `id`:

```
delete t 
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.post_id = t.post_id 
and tt.start_date = t.start_date and tt.end_date = t.end_date 
and t.id > tt.id;
```

Since this a large table, proper indexes are needed to make the process run as fast as possible.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k5PnNCPwCrh2nWYb5FPk32/2).
For this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `post_id` INTEGER,
  `start_date` VARCHAR(4),
  `end_date` VARCHAR(4),
  `views` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tablename
  (`id`, `post_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `views`)
VALUES
  ('1', '55', 'XXXX', 'YYYY', '90'),
  ('2', '55', 'XXXX', 'YYYY', '1'),
  ('3', '55', 'XXXX', 'YYYY', '1'),
  ('4', '65', 'AAAA', 'BBBB', '10'),
  ('5', '65', 'AAAA', 'BBBB', '2'),
  ('6', '65', 'AXXX', 'BYYY', '100'),
  ('7', '65', 'AXXX', 'BYYY', '200'),
  ('8', '75', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', '1');
```

Results:

```
| id  | post_id | start_date | end_date | views |
| --- | ------- | ---------- | -------- | ----- |
| 1   | 55      | XXXX       | YYYY     | 92    |
| 4   | 65      | AAAA       | BBBB     | 12    |
| 6   | 65      | AXXX       | BYYY     | 300   |
| 8   | 75      | CCCC       | CCCC     | 1     |
```